# remove duplicate documents in mongodb aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregate

I have offers collection that look like below, each document has offer id and place.

```
[
  {
    "_id": "p1-o1",
    "place": "1"
  },
  {
    "_id": "p1-o2",
    "place": "1"
  },
  {
    "_id": "p1-on",
    "place": "1"
  },
  {
    "_id": "p2-p1",
    "place": "2"
  },
  {
    "_id": "p2-o2",
    "place": "2"
  },
  {
    "_id": "p2-on",
    "place": "2"
  },
  ....
  {
    "_id": "pn-0n",
    "place": "n" 
  }
]
```

I need to aggregate and result a stream of paginated documents like below, where each page has a single offer from a single place,

**for first page:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "p1-o1",
    "place": "1"
  },
  {
    "_id": "p2-o1",
    "place": "2"
  },
  .....
  {
    "_id": "pn-o1",
    "place": "n" 
  }
]
```

**for second page**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "p1-o2",
    "place": "1"
  },
  {
    "_id": "p2-o2",
    "place": "2"
  },
  .....
  {
    "_id": "pn-on",
    "place": "n" 
  }
]
```

where **"p1-o1"** is the first offer in the first place and so on ...

Comment: _id by default is unique , you cannot have duplicated values in _id ...

Comment: @R2D2 I have updated the example, but the uniqueness is the place id in the page.

Comment: "each page has a single offer from a single place" ... but then your examples don't show this.  Would you clarify?